# How to get Id and Text value of a kivy button as string?

Tags: python, kivy

I have an app with multiple buttons and I need to get id and text value of the button as string when it is pressed. The grabbed Ids and Text valus of the button will then be passed to another function for further processing. For simplicity I wrote this sample programme.

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

########################################################################
class KVMyHBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass


########################################################################
class ExampleApp(App):
    def Pressbtn(self, *args):
        print'Pressed button'
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def build(self):

        return KVMyHBoxLayout()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.run()
```

kv file

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 32

<KVMyHBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MyButton:
        id:"idBtn1"
        text: "Btn1"
        background_color: 1,0,0,1
        on_press:app.Pressbtn()
    MyButton:
        id:"idBtn2"
        text: "Btn2"
        background_color: 0,1,0,1
        on_press:app.Pressbtn()
    Label:
        text: "ID"
        background_color: 0,0,1,1
    Label:
        text: "Text"
        background_color: 1,0,1,1
```

When a button is pressed its corresponding values of id and text will be shown in the ID and Text labels. Currently the above code only print **Pressed button** when button is pressed. I want to know how to get id and text value of button pythonically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you must pass the button instance explicitly to the method when it is called from the kv:

```
on_press: app.Pressbtn(self)
```

You can then use the instance reference to modify the button or see its attributes, you do not need the `id`. If you want to get the `id`, you can only do it using the `ids` dictionary of the button parent.

An example based on your code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv_file = '''
<MyButton@Button>:
    color: .8,.9,0,1
    font_size: 32

<KVMyHBoxLayout>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MyButton:
        id:"idBtn1"
        text: "Btn1"
        background_color: 1,0,0,1
        on_press:app.Pressbtn(self)
    MyButton:
        id:"idBtn2"
        text: "Btn2"
        background_color: 0,1,0,1
        on_press:app.Pressbtn(self)
    Label:
        id: lobj
        text: "Object"
        background_color: 1,0,1,1

    Label:
        id: lid
        text: "ID"
        background_color: 0,0,1,1
    Label:
        id: ltext
        text: "Text"
        background_color: 1,0,1,1
'''


class KVMyHBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ExampleApp(App):
    def Pressbtn(self, instance):
        instance.parent.ids.lobj.text = str(instance)
        instance.parent.ids.ltext.text = instance.text
        instance.parent.ids.lid.text= self.get_id(instance)

    def get_id(self,  instance):
        for id, widget in instance.parent.ids.items():
            if widget.__self__ == instance:
                return id

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv_file)
        return KVMyHBoxLayout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.run()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Edit:**

If you define the widget (button) in the .py file you do not need to pass the instance to the function, it is passed automatically as argument:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(FirstScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)    
        layout=BoxLayout(orientation="vertical",size_hint_y= None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))                
        for i in range(50):
                btn = Button(text="Button"+str(i),
                             id=str(i),
                             size_hint=(None, None),
                             on_press=self.Press_auth)               #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<           
                layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView()
        root.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(root)

    def Press_auth(self,instance):     
        print(str(instance))

class TestScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
        super(TestScreenManager,  self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(FirstScreen())

class ExampleApp(App):
    def build(self):           
        return TestScreenManager()

def main():
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks it works I am using button inside a screen when I press button it returns screen's object `<Screen name='FirstScreen''>` any idea how to get buttons instance which is inside a layout inside  the screen.

Comment: @Eka this code works even if the button is inside a layout inside a `Screen` (except to get the `id`). If you can´t make it work properly, edit the question by adding the code to see if I can help you. Best regards.

Comment: This is my code https://pastebin.com/PDQpXbkU  I am creating a Scrollview  boxlayout with button dynamically in the screen class. This `on_press=lambda a:self.Press_auth(self)` i took it from some sample code and it detects press event but the object its passing is `<Screen name='FirstScreen''>`

Comment: @Eka you only need to replace `on_press = lambda to: self.Press_auth (self)` with `on_press=self.Press_auth`. I edited the answer. Best regards.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. initially I tried this `on_press=self.Press_auth()` . it throwed me an error. once more thank  you

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function something along these lines. In your KV file:

```
 ToggleButton:
     text: 'Label'
     id: halftimebutton
     on_state: root.callback(self)
```

And then in your .py file you can do this:

```
def callback_halftime_state(self, instance):
    if instance.state == 'down':
        self.halftime == True
    else:
        self.halftime == False
```

This is of course showing the instance.state - but it could be any **attribute** of the button that Kivy exposes; **instance.text**, **instance.id**, etc.

Answer (score 0):

example to get button text on button click :

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
def build(self):

    VB = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical', padding=50,spacing="10")

    Atbtn = Button(text="AT (Automata Theory)", font_size="25sp")
    Atbtn.bind(on_press=self.callback)

    Pybtn = Button(text="Python", font_size="25sp")
    Pybtn.bind(on_press=self.callback)


    VB.add_widget(Atbtn)
    VB.add_widget(Pybtn)

    return VB

def callback(self, instance):
    print(instance.text)
```