# How to make a button delete itself?

Tags: python, kivy

So in Kivy the way you usually delete buttons is by accessing their id or name or something. Is there any way which you could access the info of a button that is pressed so that it may delete itself when pressed? Assuming you have very many buttons and you don't know the id or you have 100 buttons and it would take forever?

Comment: A [Button](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.button.html) is a [Label](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label) which is itself a [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget), and you can call [clear_widgets()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets) on Widget instances of widgets. I don't use Kivy, this is just a cursory glance of mine through the documentation to get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Remove a widget

Use [remove_widget()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.remove_widget) to ***remove a widget*** from the children list.

```
    self.parent.remove_widget(self)
```

## Remove all widgets / buttons

Use [clear_widgets()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.clear_widgets) to **remove all children / buttons** from a widget

```
        self.parent.clear_widgets()
```

## Many Buttons

Implement a class with inheritance of `Button`, and a method `on_touch_down` with `collide_point()` function to check for collision of the touch with our widget.

[Kivy » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> ...
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

### Snippets

```
class CustomButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"\nCustomButton.on_touch_down: text={self.text}")
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)    # remove a widget / button
            # self.parent.clear_widgets()    # remove all children/ buttons
            return True    # consumed on_touch_down & stop propagation / bubbling
        return super(CustomButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
```

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_string("""
<Demo>:
    cols: 10
""")


class CustomButton(Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"\nCustomButton.on_touch_down: text={self.text}")
            self.parent.remove_widget(self)    # remove a widget / button
            # self.parent.clear_widgets()    # remove all children / buttons
            return True    # consumed on_touch_down & stop propagation / bubbling
        return super(CustomButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)


class Demo(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Demo, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.create_buttons()

    def create_buttons(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.add_widget(CustomButton(id="Button" + str(i), text="Button"+str(i)))


class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Demo()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: App Started]
[image: Button0 - Deleted]
[image: Buttons 51 and 30 - Deleted]

Answer (score 0):

I am not very good at Kivy, but there is a pretty good explanation [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171309/how-to-get-id-and-text-value-of-a-kivy-button-as-string)

Here is the gist of what you might need:

First, you must pass the button instance explicitly to the method when it is called from the kv:

`on_press: app.Pressbtn(self)`
You can then use the instance reference to modify the button or see its attributes, you do not need the id. If you want to get the id, you can only do it using the ids dictionary of the button parent.

Comment: After you find the button ID you can just assign it to a variable and use the delete function (whatever it is) to delete it