# How do you access the text of a button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I’m trying to check if a text is in a list of buttons in Kivy and return the buttons that have the text, how can I do this? Would appreciate any help. Tried accessing the text through

```
Button[‘text’]
```

But it doesn’t seem to work

I have a list item button class

```
class ProjectListButton (ListItemButton):
   pass
```

which shows on a ListView in one screen, here is the ListView

```
 ListView:
            id: project_list_view
            adapter:
                ListAdapter(data=[], cls=mainfile.ProjectListButton)
```

I have a screen where I put data that would show on the ListView, but now I want to put a function to a button that returns the buttons that have specific strings in it

Im trying to do this

```
search_string1 = ObjectProperty(None)
    search_string2 = ObjectProperty(None)

    def sortlist(self):
        if any(self.search_string1.text and self.search_string2 in s for s in ProjectListButton['text']):
```

but it doesn't work also tried assessing through the list adapter and still doesn't work

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: done, would appreciate if you can help

Comment: It seems that you have not read the content of the link, what you have added is not an MRE.

Comment: The code posted on stack overflow should be entirely self contained. Meaning -- a random user should be able to copy your code into their editor and run it. This encourages users to help and they are more likely to help you when you make it easy for them to do so.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Id and Text value of a kivy button as string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171309/how-to-get-id-and-text-value-of-a-kivy-button-as-string)

Comment: Honestly the code is too long, I've gone way too far in the project and i can put an MRE, all I need to know is how you can gain access to the text in a button in kivy, in what value is a text in a button stored in kivy

Comment: "Honestly the code is too long" <- You aren't being asked to post your code, you're being asked to post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The `ListView`  (and the `ProjectListButtons`) can be accessed via the `ids`, but I cannot provide the precise command with your limited code provided. It would look something like `buttons_list = <something>.ids.project_list_view.container.children`. You can then access the `text` property of each of those `ProjectListButtons` as normal.

Comment: It’s not showing any errors but it’s not working, I’m trying to check If a string is in a button text and return the buttons that have the string

Answer (score 0):

To put it in simple terms, here's what you can do to **access the text on a button**

1. Give the button an `id`
2. Use `ObjectProperty()` to parse it to the python code
3. In the python code, you can access it via `self.buttonid.text`